# seeing something looked or seeing that something looked?

Tags: participles

> 1 Seeing the table cluttered, I decided to tidy it up.
>
> 2 Seeing everything looked so in order, we didn't clean anything else.

Are they correct? Or should they be as follows:

> 3 Seeing that the table was cluttered, I decided to tidy it up.
>
> 4 Seeing that everything looked so in order, we didn't clean anything else.

Answer (score 0):

**After edit**

3. Seeing (that) the table was cluttered, I decided to tidy it up.
4. Seeing (that) everything looked **(well) in order**, we didn't clean anything else.

**Before edit**

3. Seeing (that) the table was cluttered, I decided to tidy it up.
4. Seeing (that) everything looked **so good in order**, we didn't clean anything else.

I think it's "so good in order" instead of "so in order"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ko/%EC%82%AC%EC%A0%84/%EC%98%81%EC%96%B4/seeing-that

Comment: It would be "well in order", not "good in order", but simply "in order"is also fine.

Comment: Dear The Photon, Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Could you answer explicitly. I asked: Are the correct? Can you answer YES/NO?